# Пытаюсь поднять тунель на strongswan

Tags: linux

Связка такая: сервер <-> клиенты на win7

В конфигурационном файле `right=%any`, потому что у клиентов динамические IP.

Но при старте самого тунеля, выдается ошибка:

> unable to resolve %any, initiate aborted

Как я понимаю, не может разрезолвить any. Днсы в порядке.

Буду рад любым подсказкам.

ipsec.conf:

```
conn IPsec

        left=45.58.46.74
        leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
        leftid=45.58.46.74
        leftcert=fullchain.pem
        leftauth=pubkey

        right=%any
        rightid=%any
        rightauth=pubkey
        rightdns=8.8.8.8
        auto=add

        keyexchange=ikev2
        type=tunnel
```

> May  5 12:31:37 Devserver charon: 08[ENC] generating IKE_AUTH response 1 [ N(AUTH_FAILED) ]
>   May  5 12:31:37 Devserver charon: 08[NET] sending packet: from 45.58.46.74[4500] to 5.31.156.60[24018] (80 bytes)
>   May  5 12:31:37 Devserver charon: 08[IKE] IKE_SA (unnamed)[4] state change: CONNECTING => DESTROYING

Как я понимаю, авторизация по ключам не проходит.

Comment: используйте L2TP/IPSec. И начните с самого простого - ключи в топку, используйте PSK. Это позволит отладить сам туннель. Конфигурации рабочие, если что, есть на сайте strongswan....

Comment: согласно описанию опции [left/rightid](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ConnSection), её значением не может быть `%any`.

Comment: нашел решение в итоге?